# Select field WTForm flask dropdown TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I have edited this question facing a different issue

```
  File "/home/amar/tts/FLASKAPP/voicetune/venv/lib/python3.7/site-packages/wtforms/fields/core.py", line 471, in pre_validate
for v, _ in self.choices:
TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not iterable
```

form.py file

```
    language = SelectField(u'Language', coerce=str)
```

in routes.py file

```
def dashboard():
  form = DashboardForm()
  form.language.choices = [(lang.language_name,lang.language_label) for lang in Languages.query.all()]

  return render_template('dashboard.html', title='Dashboard', form=form)
```

dashboard.html file

```
    {{ form.language(class="form-control btn btn-info dropdown-toggle") }}
```

Comment: Are you sure you need `coerce=str`? This might be the problem cause it will cast your choice value to `str` while probably it must be `int` as it is id.

Comment: Please provide some more code: how you create your form and validate it.

Comment: I have edited the question  as I have added different code previously

Comment: It looks like your choices are `None` on language field Please provide code where you are creating form instance (probably routes.py).

Comment: @stasiekz please check I have added routes.py code

Comment: please show the fragment where you validate your form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method I used in a previous project to select multiple field using a form.

```
Class add(Form)
conceptList = SelectMultipleField('conceptList', coerce=int)

# Dynamic adding a concept
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    Form.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
    # Get the concepts from concepts table
    self.conceptList.choices = [(c.concept_id, c.concept_name) for c in Concepts.query.order_by('concept_name')]
```

and on the views file I used this method to retrieve the data from the form.

```
for concept_id in form.conceptList.data:
    concept = Concepts.query.get(concept_id)
    new_tool.concepts_tools.append(concept)
```

It is not in a dropdown menu thought, but you might find it useful. The difference is that the choices are declared in the form. I am not sure about this, but I think you need to change the selectField from string to int and also refer the id of the languages as well in the choices. Something like this:

```
language = SelectField(u'Language', coerce=int)

 def dashboard():
     form = DashboardForm()
     form.language.choices = [(lang.language_id,lang.language_name,lang.language_label) for lang in Languages.query.all()] 
return render_template('dashboard.html', title='Dashboard', form=form)
```

Comment: I m referring this doc.  https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fields.html?highlight=fields.selectfield#wtforms.fields.SelectField

Comment: Edited my initial comment based on the document you posted. You can have a look at it.

Comment: I have removed my if form.validate_on_submit() condition for time being to work this out ... question is still remain